# WindowsPC/Androidタブレットで同じWebページを表示したい

Tags: android, java, html5

WindowsPC/AndroidごとにWebページを用意するのではなく、
両方から1つのWebページを表示したいです。

PCはWebページを参照するだけなのですが、タブレットはHTML5でバーコードをスキャンもさせたいです。

① WindowsPC/AndroidでWebページを共有する際に発生する問題を教えて下さい。
→ レイアウトが崩れたりしませんか？ボタンサイズの問題 etc...

② HTML5を使ってバーコードスキャンって、実際どうなんですか？
→ HTML5を使ってバーコードスキャンするよりも、javaでAndroidアプリを作る方が安全だと思うんです

Comment: これは質問を二つに分けたほうがいいかもしれません。 また、回答の範囲も広いと思われますので、以下 2 つの点について明らかにはした方が良いです。 1. HTML5 であなたが作ったページに、どのような問題が発生し、何について解決したいと考えていますか？ 2. バーコードスキャンは HTML5 を使いどうやって実装されました／される予定ですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

>1.HTML5 であなたが作ったページに、どのような問題が発生し、何について解決したいと考えていますか？
レイアウトのズレ and JavaScriptがPC/Androidで同じく動いてくれるかです。

> 2. バーコードスキャンは HTML5 を使いどうやって実装されました／される予定ですか？
JavaScriptのライブラリを探してきて、実装する予定です。
残念ながらそのライブラリは、まだ見つけられていません。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。なにも手を付けていないのですね。この質問には、「HTMLを共通で使いたい」「HTMLでバーコード読み取りの方法は？」「HTMLの読み取りはネイティブほど安全ではないけど、どうするの？」と３つの興味深い質問が含まれていますので、ここは編集して、１つに絞ったほうが良いです。それでも回答の範囲は広いと思いますので、自分の試行過程やサンプルを出すか、具体的に問題意識を回答者に与えるようにしてください。

Comment: 例えば Code128,Code93, Code39,などに対応した Pure JavaScript ライブラリがあります。[Github - Eddie Larsson JOB](https://github.com/EddieLa/JOB)

Comment: 二次元バーコードの場合もZXing(ゼブラクロッシング)を移植すればJSだけで認識できなくはないですね

Answer (score 0):

取りあえず、ＰＣとスマホ兼用のページを作るのは如何でしょう？
例えば、ALLAboutさんが「レスポンシブな2カラムレイアウトを作るCSSの書き方」
というのを書かれています。(2019年11月20日現在)
https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/463388/
これは、ＰＣ用とモバイル用と、css を別けるだけで、１つのhtml を兼用出来ます。
片方だけに必要なリンクを表示させることも出来ます。
ただ、ＰＣではメニューは左右・スマホでは上下等、
兼用出来るレイアウトを考える必要はあります。

Answer (score 0):

WindowsPC/AndroidごとにWebページを用意するのではなく、
両方から1つのWebページを表示したいとのことですが、WordPressで作成すると、
PCではPCのフォーマットで、スマホではスマホのフォーマットで
表示されるサイトを作ることができます。
このようなやり方ではだめですか？